# Write Join Query in ASP.NET MVC using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just finished reading Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET MVC book as an introduction to ASP.NET  MVC.

However, I ran into a situation where I have to join multiple tables but with Freeman's Method, I am unable to.

Please See my Code Below

EFEmployeeRepository.cs (In My Concrete Folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HRMS.Domain.Abstract;
using HRMS.Domain.Entities;



namespace HRMS.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFEmployeeRepository : IEmployeesRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();           

        public Employee getEmployeeByID(int User_ID)
        {

            // I want to Join the Employee Table with the User Table to Get Employee Details

            Employee employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_ID == User_ID);

            return employee;

        }
    }
}
```

IEmployeesRepository.cs (Absctract Folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HRMS.Domain.Entities;


namespace HRMS.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IEmployeesRepository
    {

        //Get employee Details
        Employee getEmployeeByID (int User_ID);

    }
}
```

I will need to Join the Employee model with the user Model for a particular Employee and return the data to a controller

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a *web framework*. It has nothing to do with repositories and storage. I suspect you really want to ask about *Entity Framework*. EF is an *ORM*, it doesn't need any joins. You should define proper navigation properties and relations instead. In the end, you should consider very carefully where and how to use the Repository pattern so that you don't end up loading one big object when you could retrieve just two properties with a LINQ query

Comment: "I am unable to" doesn't really explain the problem. What is stopping you?

Comment: When your Employee has a User nav property then all you need is a `.Include()`. Post the relevant parts of the classes.

Comment: If your `Employee` class has a `User` property, all you'd need to return the data for both entities would be to simply load the `Employee` class. The `User` instance would come along almost "transparently" through lazy or eager loading. You'd need to call `Include()` only to force eager loading.

Comment: If you want to load only *some* properties, you *shouldn't* return the entire entities. Write a LINQ query that returns only what you want, eg `Employees.Where(emp=>emp.User.ID==currentID).Select(emp=>new MyDTO{Name=emp.Name,UserName=emp.User.UserName});`. After all, you don't need to load the employee's picture just to post `Hello John`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, can you recommend more materials/ books for further study

Comment: @devloper2009 there's a *lot* of information. Start with the [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) site itself in the docs. There are a lot of tutorials, videos and courses too. For example you'll find free courses in Microsoft's Virtual Academy site. You can also get 3 months free access to Pluralsight's courses through the Visual Studio Dev Essentials program (also free)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var empDetails = (from emp in Context.Employees
             join us in Context.User on emp.User_ID equals us.User_ID
             where emp.User_ID == User_ID
             select new UserDataModel
             {
               User_ID=us.User_ID,
               UserName=us.username,
               EmployeeId=emp.EmployeeId
             }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Your Data Model :

```
public class UserDataModel
{
  public int User_ID {get; set;}
  public String UserName {get; set;}
  public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: ORMs have relations, they don't need joins. Instead of using joins, just write `Include(employee=>employee.User)`. Or `where employee.User.ID=someUserID`

Comment: @Adrita Sharma, How do i get the data in my View

Comment: This is for those who have a habit of writing SQL queries. Result is same if you use entity's relations.

Comment: I get this error trying to get data from the result

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<JoinIterator>d__37`4[HRMS.Domain.Entities.Employee,HRMS.Domain.Entities.User,System.Int32,HRMS.Domain.ORModels.UserEmployeeModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HRMS.Domain.ORModels.UserEmployeeModel'.

Comment: Add .FirstOrDefault() to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If the FK relationship is maintained properlu in DB then include will work. If not, then join is the only option.

Comment: @AdriSharma `Include` deals with eager loading. It has nothing to do with the database or FK **constraints**. *Navigation properties* define relations and again have nothing to do with FK constraints. If the classes don't have the proper properties, fix the bug. Don't cover it up with joins. If you have to use joins, why use an ORM at all? Might as well write a view in the database and avoid the complex code. Now, if the keys have no **indexes** EF, view joins or LIN joins will be equally slow.